# Creating a contact form which displays error when not filled in? (validation)

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, contact-form

I asked this question before about trying to create a contact form which allows validation (displays an error when not filled in or filled in incorrectly) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331369/creating-a-contact-form-which-displays-error-when-not-filled-in

The end functions don't have to work (meaning it doesn't have to send but it will still be nice for this to work 100%) because I'm creating a template of this but I do want the validation and message to come up if it's filled incorrectly. Please take a look and see what I did wrong, thanks in advance.

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="hr dotted clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- Contact Form -->
            <form action='index.html' method='post' id='contact_form'>
                    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
                <div class="hr dotted clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
                <ul>                        
                    <li class="clearfix"> 
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type='text' name='name' id='name' />
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <p id='name_error' class='error'>Insert a Name</p>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="clearfix"> 
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type='text' name='email' id='email' />
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <p id='email_error' class='error'>Enter a valid email address</p>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="clearfix"> 
                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                        <input type='text' name='subject' id='subject' />
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <p id='subject_error' class='error'>Enter a message subject</p>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="clearfix"> 
                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea name='message' id='message' rows="30" cols="30"></textarea>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <p id='message_error' class='error'>Enter a message</p>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="clearfix"> 

                    <p id='mail_success' class='success'>Thank you. I'll get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
                    <p id='mail_fail' class='error'>Sorry, an error has occured. Please try again later.</p>
                    <div id="button">
                    <input type='submit' id='send_message' class="button" value='Submit' />
                    </div>
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
            </form>  
        </div>
```

And here's my code for the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#send_message').click(function(e){


                e.preventDefault();

                var error = false;
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var subject = $('#subject').val();
                var message = $('#message').val();


                if(name.length == 0){
                    var error = true;
                    $('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    $('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
                }
                if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
                    var error = true;
                    $('#email_error').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    $('#email_error').fadeOut(500);
                }
                if(subject.length == 0){
                    var error = true;
                    $('#subject_error').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    $('#subject_error').fadeOut(500);
                }
                if(message.length == 0){
                    var error = true;
                    $('#message_error').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    $('#message_error').fadeOut(500);
                }


                if(error == false){

                    $('#send_message').attr({'disabled' : 'true', 'value' : 'Sending...' });


                    $.post("send_email.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){

                        if(result == 'sent'){

                             $('#button').remove();

                            $('#mail_success').fadeIn(500);
                        }else{

                            $('#mail_fail').fadeIn(500);

                            $('#send_message').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Submit');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });    
        });
```

And part of CSS:

```
p.error                             {margin-left:140px; margin-top:10px;}
    #contact_form ul                    {float:left;}
    #contact_form ul li                 {margin:10px 0; list-style:none; position:relative; clear:both;}
    #contact_form label                 {line-height:35px; width:100px; text-align:right; float:left; margin-right:10px;}
    #contact_form input#name,
    #contact_form input#email,
    #contact_form input#subject,
    #contact_form textarea              {float:left; padding:8px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; margin-left:10px; background:#fcfcfc; -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px;}
    #contact_form input#name,
    #contact_form input#email,
    #contact_form input#subject         {width:400px;}
    #contact_form textarea              {width:500px;height:150px; resize: none;}
    #contact_form input.button          {float:right;}
```

Comment: btw, the thing that doesn't work is that the error message displays at the start when the page load and when I type in - say - an e-mail in correct format, then the error message disappears... this should be the opposite but it's not working that way...

Comment: Check my answer, I've updated the example to hide the errors at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the variable `error` declared several times. In [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ofoner/1/edit) you have you code rectified, it runs ok.

edit 1: Regarding your comment I've [updated](http://jsbin.com/ofoner/2/edit) the code. Now the erros don't show at the beginning.

edit 2: *"because I'm creating a template of this"* — in that case I would recommend you make your code more abstract, or to use a library for form validation.

Comment: thanks so much, can you tell me what you've changed to get rid of the error message? btw, I just applied the code to my dreamweaver, still get the error message at the beginning, and it only 'fades' aways once correctly formatted messages are typed in the input box.

Comment: Check the css, I've added `display:none` to the error messages.

Comment: ok it works now, one last question if you can answer - mail_success and mail_fail doesn't seem to be functioning (I want mail_success message to display when everything is typed correctly) and mail_fail to display when it hasn't been typed.

Comment: welcome, take a look in the [about section](http://stackoverflow.com/about): 1. Good answers are voted up and rise to the top  2. The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted"   ;)

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this on my website for validation :

1. rename the id's of the elements you want checked to "1", "2", "3" etc.
2. rename the id's of the error messages you want displayed to "1a", "2a", "3a" etc.

Then I did something like this :

```
function validate()
{
   for(i = 1; i< totalelements; i++)
   {
      if(document.getElementById(i).length >= 0 )
      {
         $("#" + i + "a").fadeIn(500);
      }

      else
      {
         $("#" + i + "a").fadeOut(500);
      }
   }
}
```

Now the only thing you gotta do is assign the function somewhere (on a button, keyup/down etc)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you just try

input type='button' id='send_message' class="button" value='Submit' />

instead of

input type='submit' id='send_message' class="button" value='Submit' />

Comment: doesn't do much this one :/

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery validation plugin - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

This is very strong validation plugin. It will just take you 10 seconds to apply this to your contact form. This is also my favourite one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a keyword added in HTML5 for required fields:

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
```

However, this won't be cross-browser so in such case the best approach could be a jquery plugin.